# Reducing MathJax size

Tags: javascript, size, mathjax

I'd like to use MathJax on my website, which has a limited webspace and should not have cross-site requests (privacy, load times). But the whole MathJax tool is 50+ MB. Do I really need everything from it? I already deleted `docs` and `test` because this is not needed on the server, but they were only some KB.

What parts of the whole MathJax toolset do I really need to have it work? I assume I can also delete the `unpacked` folder (15+ MB)? What else do I not need to save space? What are the essentials to have MathJax run?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a comprehensive guide from their documentation:

https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-docs/wiki/Guide%3A-reducing-size-of-a-mathjax-installation

They end up with a 1.7MB library size, 700KB after GZIP compression. Of course the amount you'll be able to trim out depends on your specific project requirements.

Comment: you may also consider https://github.com/yuexue/small_mathjax , it small python tool for reducing the size of mathjax.